# Zope z3c.relationfield RelationList and wrong permissions for custom content type

Tags: plone, zope

I have a simple content type with a few fields one of which uses RelationList to relate to items of another content type. As a simple user I can create the content type, and select the related items. This is saved ok, however if I edit the content type the list is empty . If I assign the role 'manager' to the user, then if I edit the content type I can see the items (as expected). 
How can I set the correct permission so that editing as a user would contain the items? I tried to find anything related inside the ZMI and sections as security/workflow/permissions etc but this hasn't worked for me.

Any suggestions highly welcome.

```
from z3c.relationfield.schema import RelationList

class ILecture(form.Schema):

    form.widget(relatedItems=QuerySourceFieldCheckboxWidget)
    relatedItems = RelationList(
        title=u"Clips",
        description=,
        default=[],
        value_type=RelationChoice(title=_(u"Related"),
                   source=ObjPathSourceBinder(object_provides=IPlumiVideo.__identifier__)),
        required=True,
   )
```

YG. I've [posted](https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.relationfield/issues/5) that but since I'm not sure how active the project is I post it here too.

Comment: Don't get if your simple user normally can or can not see referenced contents.

Answer (score 0):

As much am getting you point i think you should use `write_permission=permissions.ModifyPortalContent`
or something similar in your content Field